# Firebase array length binding with the DOM

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

How can I display a simple firebase array length in the DOM that get updated?
This way is not working for me:

jsfiddle.net/L4ur6zu7/1

```
var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
$scope.posts = $firebase(ref.child('posts')).$asArray();
```

DOM:

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts">
    {{ post.title }}
    {{ post.votes.length }} // this is not working 
</div>
<span>
    number of posts: {{ posts.length }} // this is working
</span>
```

Firebase structure :

```
{
  "posts" : {
    "-JeM0HL0eeaJqrsW_sa3" : {
      "title" : "Test Post",
      "votes" : {
        "-JeM0J8OqezF_Caod9ed" : {
          "creator" : "nabil"
        },
        "-JeM0JEfwfEf_VAhsV7-" : {
          "creator" : "nabil"
        }
        "-JeM0JNgCbUyOHTFPBY2" : {
          "creator" : "nabil"
        },
        "-JeM0JSi_D_Zf0U6eIUr" : {
          "creator" : "nabil"
        },
        "-JeM0JX71q1Qt4rmHA42" : {
          "creator" : "nabil"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If `posts.length` works (as you seem to indicate by `// this is working`), what is the question?

Comment: the child array is not working {{ post.votesArray.length }} // this is not working

Comment: Aha... so is there an array called `votesArray` under your `post`? In that case you could set up a separate sync-point for the post's votes with `$asArray()` in your controller. Or set the `length` yourself using a `$loaded()` handler on the posts.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you share either a sample of your data structure or the code that you used to create it. Without those, I am (and probably others are) struggling to figure out what is happening.

Comment: @nabil Did you figure this out?  Do you have a fiddle I could see?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/L4ur6zu7/1/

Comment: `votes` is an object not an array as you previously mentioned, so you won't have a `length` property to tell you how many keys it has

Comment: posts also not array but lenght works for it!